# Redirect certain websites

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm starting up a VPN service, and am attempting to block certain bandwidth-hungry websites, such as Netflix, torrent sites, etc.
Naturally I am offering a paid service as well as the free one, to enable users to access most of these blocked websites (except torrent sites); the paid VPN servers will be on different machines than the free service.

I have tried to block access to Netflix via the `/etc/hosts` file, but however I am still able to access Netflix when connected to one of my VPN servers.
Contents of my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 www2.netflix.com
127.0.0.1 www1.netflix.com
127.0.0.1 www.netflix.com
127.0.0.1 netflix.com
```

The VPS connection gives absolutely no access to the server machine itself, so I'm thinking that perhaps the PPTP VPS connection is bypassing the `/etc/hosts/` file?
If so, how can I get these websites blocked so no user can access them via the VPS connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the problem lies with your */etc/nsswitch.conf* file, which handles, in *Nix-type systems, the databases to be queried for certain services.

One of the lines, in *my /etc/nsswitch.conf*, is:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

This shows that, in order to identify a host, first *local files* (meaning, */etc/hosts*) are queried, then, last, dns. If in your system *files* is not the first resource to be used, then the definitions you have made may be avoided.

You should configure your /etc/nsswitch.conf file likewise, this might solve your problem.